# use trait variable undefined

Tags: laravel, traits

I am trying to use trait because I will put the code in several files as it is an api connection.
But when calling the variable that displays the values returned by the api, it is showing undefined in the controller.

App/Http/Traits/UserConnect.php

```
namespace App\Http\Traits;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions;

trait UserConnect
{

    public function connectInfo(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $url = "api_url";
            $response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
                ],
            ]);
            $result = json_decode($response->getBody());

            return $result;

        }catch (\Exception  $e){
            dd($e);
        }
    }

}
```

Controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Traits\UserConnect;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    use UserConnect;

    public function page(Request $request)
    {
        $api = $this->connectInfo($result);
        dd($api);
    }
```

$result is returning undefined but $ api is forcing 1 variable.

Comment: you are sending `$result` while you just have `$request`

Comment: `$api = $this->connectInfo($request);`

Comment: Thanks @Arun,working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call should be `$api = $this->connectInfo(`<strike>`$result`</strike>`$request);` because your function declaration accepts **Request** `public function connectInfo(Request $request)`